# Set ParseFile images in a ListView using custom ArrayList<MyOwnParseClass> in a custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, adapter, listviewitem

I am using a ListView to show all records from parse. With a custom Class called ListadoObjetoParse that contains some attributes like *name*, *address* and **ParseFile**, this last one contains an image of the record. Data object that contains everything is an *ArrayList of ListadoObjetoParse* called **datos**.  The problems comes in the custom Adapter (*RestaurantesAdapter*) when trying to get images (*ParseFile*) and populate in the listView from that object named "datos". Its not possible to fetch the image as a ParseFile and convert to Bitmap to show in the listView. I have seen only one way using GetDAtaInBackGround method. Below i show CustomAdapter and Class ListadoObjetoParse.

I'd appreciate any help to show some light with this as i am stucked since long time. Thank you very much

/*CUSTOM ADAPTER*/

```
public class RestaurantesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListadoObjetoParse> {
   private Context context;
   private ArrayList<ListadoObjetoParse> datos;

   public RestaurantesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListadoObjetoParse> datos) {
      super(context, R.layout.activity_mostrar_listado_restaurantes, datos);
      this.context = context;
      this.datos = datos;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         View item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.mostrar_listado_detalle_restaurante, null);


         final ImageView imagen = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.imgRestaurante);

         //Here i fetch Image from the class ListadoObjetoParse with method getImagen             
         ParseFile i = datos.get(position).getImagen();

         /*Expected to do this, but of course not possible convert*/
         Bitmap i = (Bitmap) datos.get(position).getImagen();



       /*Example Way that is shown in tutorials and parse to fetch the image. But doesn't work for my "datos" object*/
        i.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                //Convert ParseFile image of item to Bitmap and show in the listItem
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                imagen.setImageBitmap(bmp);


            } else {
                Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");

            }
        }
    });

    //Setting name of item in listview
    TextView nombre = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvNombre);
    nombre.setText(datos.get(position).getNombre());

    //Setting phone number of item in listview
    TextView telefono = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvTelefono);
    telefono.setText(datos.get(position).getTelefono());

   //Setting address of item in listview
    TextView direccion = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvDireccion);
    direccion.setText(datos.get(position).getDireccion());

    return item;
}
```

/*LISTADOOBJECTOPARSE.CLASS*/

public class ListadoObjetoParse {

```
private String nombre;
private String direccion;
private String ciudad;
private String telefono;
private ParseFile imagen;


//*CONSTRUCT*/

public ListadoObjetoParse() {} 

public ListadoObjetoParse(String nombre, String ciudad, String direccion, String telefono){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.telefono = telefono;

}

public ListadoObjetoParse(String nombre, String ciudad, String direccion, String telefono, ParseFile imagen){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.imagen = imagen;
}


/*METHODS*/

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getCiudad() {
    return ciudad;
}

public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String getTelefono() {return telefono;}

public void setTelefono(String telefono) {this.telefono = telefono;}


public ParseFile getImagen() {return imagen;}

public void setImagen(ParseFile imagen) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First**
Try to use ParseImageView instead Image view and load ParseFiles native:

```
ParseFile file;
ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
imageView.setParseFile(file);
imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
   @Override
   public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {

   }
 });
```

or just `imageView.loadInBackground()` if you don't need callback.

More [parse doc](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseImageView.html)

**Second**

```
ParseFile file;
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
byte[] bitmapdata = file.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get fix it thanks to your suggestions.I wasn't able to get it at the beginning, but combining ParseImagView and some comprehension of how works AdapterView could get it works. Below there is the code explained:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Inflate The view to show on the ListView Object
    View item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.mostrar_listado_detalle_restaurante, null);

    //Instanciate of ParseImageView that will content the image ParseFile
    ParseImageView foto = (ParseImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.imgRestaurante);

   //This gets the result of a search of restaurants in a previous activity
    List<ParseObject> res = BusquedaRestaurante.ObtenerObjectoParse.getObjeto();

    //We set ParseObject (Restaurant) of the List using position var
    ParseObject resf = res.get(position);

    //recover the "picture" of that restaurant
    ParseFile file = resf.getParseFile("Foto");

    //Here we check if there is a picture 
    if (file != null) {
        foto.setParseFile(file);
        foto.loadInBackground();
        Log.d("ERROR:", "Picture is set in ParseImageView");
    } else {

         Log.d("ERROR:", "There is no picture in the Restaurant photo field");
    }


    // Other


    return item;
}
```